# how to test variables in angular services

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('someService', function(){
    var foo = {}; // can not get access to this variable

    function setData(data){
        foo.data = data;
    }

    function getData(){
        return foo.data;
    }

   return {
       getData: getData,
       setData: setData
   }
})
```

how to test this two functions for set and get some data from local variable in service?

```
describe('someService', function () {
    var someService,
        foo ;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_someService_) {
        someService= _someServicee_;
    }));

    it('should return bundle id', function () {
        expect(someService.setData('test')) // foo.data toBe 'test'
    });
});
```

how to get access to foo var in service?

Answer (score -1):

You've made foo a private variable, so you'd be trying to break your own design if you wanted to get the value of the variable by a means other than using the getData function.

You're really just trying to test that what you set using the setData function is what is returned by the getData function so I'd use those so that you're testing the API instead of the forcing yourself into a specific internal implementation which would make your tests brittle.

As a side note, you should remove the parameter from the getData function since it isn't used.